# How can I check internet connection in Android Q?

Tags: java, android, connection

Before Android Q all you had to do is use the NetworkUtils class. But this class was deprecated in API 29.
I've been searching for an alternative, and I couldn't seem to find one.

So, how can I check the internet connection in Android Q?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    @IntRange(from = 0, to = 4)
public static int getConnectionType(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null) {
        return 0; // No connection
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
        if (capabilities == null) {
            return 0; // No connection
        }
        if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            return 2; // WiFi
        } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            return 1; // Cellular data
        } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
            return 3; // VPN
        } else {
            return 4; // Other network types like Ethernet
        }
    } else {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork == null || !activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            return 0; // No connection
        }
        switch (activeNetwork.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                return 2; // WiFi
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
                return 1; // Cellular data
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN:
                return 3; // VPN
            default:
                return 4; // Other network types like Ethernet
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a simple code, you can use this:

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return cm.getActiveNetwork() != null && cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork()) != null;
    } else {
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some answers recommend just checking if getNetworkCapabilities returns a non null value but if you want to check if that network could actually provide Internet, you should do this instead:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork()).hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you must still have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If you want to check if the available Internet connection actually works (or worked when last checked), use the NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED capability.

Comment: Older answers recommend using `NetworkInfo`, which is deprecated as of Android Q/API 29. Also, a small correction: Use `NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET`, otherwise you have to import it.

Comment: More information: You can only test this in Android Studio's emulator by turning off mobile data. Enabling/disabling wifi in it or even unplugging the PC's LAN cable don't seem to change anything and will always return "true", as long as mobile data is on.

Answer (score 1):

The ConnectivityManager only checks whether the smartphone could theoretically establish an Internet connection. Whether an Internet connection actually exists, e.g. if the network quality is very poor, can only be determined with a ping or a web address.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code and call isInternatAvailable(context).

```
    private static final String CMD_PING_GOOGLE = "ping -w -c 1 google.com";

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(@NonNull Context context) {
        return isConnected(context) && checkInternetPingGoogle();
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkInternetPingGoogle(){
        try {
            int a = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD_PING_GOOGLE).waitFor();
            return a == 0x0;
        } catch (IOException ioE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, ioE);
        } catch (InterruptedException iE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iE);
        }
        return false;
    }
```